# CSS: How to tell the features a certain ttf font has?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts, truetype

I have an arbitrary ttf font that I want to use in my web application.

How can I tell which characteristics like "bold", "italic" are available in this font?

Background: I want to avoid that I have to try out all the different settings like:

```
font-weight: bold;
font-style: italic;
```

in order to see which one has an effect on the appearance of the font on my web site.

Comment: if you are on windows you can view the font set by right clicking and open - usually though you would have a different ttf for each type of character

Comment: I'm pretty sure that a ttf only has a single weight and that adding font-weight: bold or other type styles merely fakes the effect. If you want true type features you need to use one of the open type formats such as what Google supplies.

Answer (score 14):

Let me cut that thought short: that's not how `ttf` (or in fact, any) font resources work. Bold, Italic, etc are separate "physical" files on your harddisk, and the kind of style toggling you see in Office applications, text editors, etc. come from the OS showing you an abstraction: it only shows you the font family name, rather than the list of individual `ttf` or `otf` files, and then shows you style/weight UI controls, which trigger an actual font resource switch from one file to another without you ever noticing.

So: if you have a single `ttf` file, that file represents only one, specific , font face expression (regular, bold, italic, bold-italic, or even something more detailed based on OpenType metadata properties).

To make things even more fun: if you want to use fonts in CSS, CSS *doesn't even care* about what a particular font resource is. It completely relies on you to tell it what it is, and you get to lie: CSS will believe you. If you use an `@font-face` rule you get to say which font file to use for a particular combination of `font-*` properties, so you're in the driving seat:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: MyFont;
  /* CSS has no idea, nor does it care, what this font "really" is */
  src: url('myfont-Bold-Italic.ttf') format("truetype");
  /* so we tell it this font is applicable to weight:100, or ultra-thin */
  font-weight: 100;
  /* and we also tell it that this font is applicable in "normal" style */
  font-style: normal;
}
```

And presto, as far as the page styling you just defined, using `MyFont` with normal style and weight 100 will load whatever `ttf` resource you said it should use. The CSS engine does not care or even know that the resource you told it to use is "actually" a bold italic expression of the font family. All it knows is that you said this font had to be used for `weight:100/style:normal` so that's what it's going to use in something like this:

```
body {
  font-family: MyFont, sans-serif /* weight mismatch, so this will probably fall through */
}

h1 {
  weight: 100; /* weight/style match: this will use myfont-Bold-Italic.ttf! */
}
```

**2019 edit**

OpenType introduced font variations (FVAR) which allows a single font to encode an infinite spectrum of variable vector graphics, which means that if the browser you're targeting supports FVAR OpenType, you can now load a single font as your `@font-face` instruction, with a new `format` string that indicates it's variable, and instead in your normal CSS indicate which specific variation you need by specifying the `font-variation-settings` property:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: MyFont;
  src: url('myfont-Bold-Italic.ttf') format("truetype-variation");
  /* no weight or style information here anymore */
}


body {
  font-family: MyFont;
  font-variation-settings: 'wght' 435;
}

h1 {
  font-variation-settings: 'wght' 116;
}
```

While "plain" CSS only supports 9 font weights (100 through 900 in steps of 100), variations can use values from 1 to 1000 in steps of 1.

Answer (score 5):

Each and every font (if weights available) comes in a separate true type format file for each and every weight of the font.

e.g.

```
Roboto.ttf
Roboto-Italic.ttf
Roboto-Bold.ttf
```

Therefore, you need to specify which is which in Your CSS file like so:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-weight: normal;
    url('fonts/Roboto.ttf') format('truetype')/*ttf*/;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-weight: bold;
    url('fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf') format('truetype')/*ttf*/;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-style: italic;
    url('fonts/Roboto-Italic.ttf') format('truetype')/*ttf*/;
}
```

In your case, you can view the particular file directly by clicking on it twice in the Windows/MacOS/Linux explorers.

If you want to use a third-party software solution, I suggest that you give **[opentype.js](http://opentype.js.org/font-inspector.html)** a look.

Comment: Note that as of the introduction of variable axes in OpenType, this is no longer strictly true. Single fonts can now encode infinitely many font weights, along (effectively) as many variation axes as a (team of) type designer(s) deems appropriate. So rather than indicating different fonts, you'd indicate just a single font, and then in your class CSS you would specify which values to clamp for which variation axes using the `font-variation-settings` CSS property.